# change default install location of windows 10 store uwp app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have a windows 10 uwp app that runs fine when i have it sideloaded in my computer or any users computer where they have full admin priviliges. i use appxbundle and click on install button to install the same. Even powershell installation works fine.

Some of our clients don't have access to C: drive and the installation of UWP app is incomplete or fails because they don't have any install permissions.

Is it possible to run UWP app stand alone or specify a different install location which is other than C drive where user has both read and write permissions .

I tried to use .exe generated in the bin folder of uwp x64/Release folder but that doesn't run as uwp doesn't support exe

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no such feature in UWP.  UWP can't change the install process when installing, which means UWP apps can't choose where apps should be installed.

But there is a setting for Windows 10 that could change the location where the UWP apps are installed.

1. You could go to the Settings app and navigate to **System** > **Storage**.
2. Under the **More Storage Settings** heading click on the link that says **Change where new content is saved**.

You can choose one drive from the drop-down menu under "**New apps will save to**" and then click Apply. A new folder called "**WindowsApps**" will be created in the drive you've chosen. And any new UWP app will be installed in this folder. Please note Windows 10 will only install new apps to the currently selected location. Existing apps do not get moved to the new location.

Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

1. Press Windows key + I together to open Settings.
2. Click on System > Storage.
3. Click on Change where new content is saved under More storage settings.
4. Select D drive using the drop down menu under New apps will save to.

You can also install an app and later move the app to a different drive.

To move an app to a different drive:

1. Press Windows key + I together to open Settings.
2. Click on Apps > Apps & features.
3. Click on the app that you want to move, and select Move.
4. Select the destination drive.